# How to add list of parameters for Power BI Custom Connector?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am trying to create a custom connector for Power BI.

I am trying to add a dynamic list of URL parameters.  I am not sure what type to use to achieve this.  I am hoping to get either a record or table style UI to display, here is what I have:

In my custom connector definition, I tried 4 different record type, and none of them are able to create an UI that allow user to enter dynamic URL params - rawRecord, recordType, recordList, recordRecord:

```
shared GetRecords = Value.ReplaceType(APIGetRecords, APIGetRecordsParams);

Record = type [ Param = text, Value = text ];
RecordList = type { Record };
RecordRecord = type [ paramType ];

APIGetRecordsParams = type function (
    name as (type text meta [
        Documentation.FieldCaption = "Names",
        Documentation.AllowedValues = SupportEndpointList
    ]),
    startTime as (type text meta [
        Documentation.FieldCaption = "Start Time",
        Documentation.FieldDescription = "The start time to get record from",
        Documentation.SampleValues = {"2020-09-13T00:00:00Z"}
    ]),
    endTime as (type text meta [
        Documentation.FieldCaption = "End Time",
        Documentation.FieldDescription = "The end time to get record from",
        Documentation.SampleValues = {"2022-09-13T02:00:00Z"}
    ]),
    rawRecord as Record.Type,
    recordType as Record,
    recordList as RecordList,
    recordRecord as RecordRecord
    ) as table meta [
        Documentation.Name = "API Get Records",
        Documentation.LongDescription = "Get records from API",
        Documentation.Examples = {[
            Description = "Another example, new message, new count!",
            Code = "HelloWorldWithDocs.Contents(""Goodbye"", 1)",
            Result = "#table({""Column1""}, {{""Goodbye""}})"
        ]}
    ];
```

The generated UI in Power BI look like this:

[image]

How can I define a custom connector so that it allow user to enter arbitrary URL parameters?